# Dump a dereferenced address in WinDbg

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to evaluate the contents of a call stack in WindDbg using the d* commands. I know that the address to the data I want to dump is at `[ebp+8]`. However when using this command WinDbg is dumping the data at ebp with an 8 byte offset. I want to dump the data pointed to by ebp+8. I've been manually `dd ebp` then manually typing the address in a subsequent `du address`.

Is there a way to instruct WinDbg to automatically dereference a pointer when dumping data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dp* command to display data pointed by pointer at ebp+8. You can also use d*p.

Answer (score 12):

you can use any d* command with the address poi(ebp+8)